# WPF automatic scroll in Textblock is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I am trying to implement vertical scroll inside my Textblock. but it is not working

```
<Window x:Class="FileManager.MainWindow" namespace:FileManager" mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{StaticResource RedStyle}" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="ExFile Manager Application" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,5,20,0"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="43" Margin="30,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select only the text file" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" Name="FileNameTextBox"/>
        <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse a file" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BrowseButton_Click" Margin="485,35,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" RenderTransformOrigin="1.047,0.821" Height="40"/>
       
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="TextBlock1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`

Comment: not working.When i add scrollviewer my butoon got disabled.

Comment: You seem to have [already posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095762/wpf-textblock-automatic-scroll-is-not-working), under a different account. Do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code get what you wanna achieve?

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="ExFile Manager Application" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,5,20,0"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="43" Margin="30,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="Select only the text file"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" Name="FileNameTextBox"/>
    <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse a file" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="485,35,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" RenderTransformOrigin="1.047,0.821" Height="40"/>
   
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="TextBlock1"
                       Text="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
        
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you have enabled the horizontal scroll bar of the `ScrollViewer`, which will cause the TextBlock to be measured with positive infinity. Consequently, the `TextBlock` will expand to its full width to display all text and the content will be displayed in one line. Your options  are:

- Remove the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` to disable horizonal scrolling, which will expand the `TextBlock` to the width of the containing `Grid` at maximum and then wrap the text.
- Assign a `Width` or `MaxWidth` to the `TextBlock`, so it does not expand beyond that size and will wrap the text to the next line once exceeding that size, therefore enabling horizontal and vertical scrolling

As a general note, your layout is odd. All your controls are overlapping in the `Grid` and you set `Margin`s to position them. What you should do instead is create rows and columns in the `Grid` to position controls or use different panels for layouting. There are plenty of options, which simplify your layout a lot. As an example with `Grid` rows an columns:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="ExFile Manager Application" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,5,20,0"/>
   <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="43"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select only the text file" Name="FileNameTextBox"/>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse a file"/>
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TextBlock1"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

You can have a look at the [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/layout?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) page for more information on layouting and WPF panels.